# using split command in shell how to know the number of files generated

Tags: shell

I am using command `split` for a large file to generate little files which are put in a folder, my problem is the folder contains over files different from my split.

I would like to know if there is a way to know how much files are generated only from my split not the number of all files in my folder.
My command  `split a 2 d`. Is there any option I can join to this command to know it?

I know  this `ls -Al | wc -l` will give me the number of files in the folder that doesn't interest me.

Comment: Does the `--verbose` option help by letting you pipe the output from split to `wc -l` or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution here is to split into a fresh directory.

Assuming that's not possible and you aren't worried about other processes operating on the directory in question you can just count the files before and after. Something like this

```
$ before=(*)
$ split a 2 d
$ after=(*)
$ echo "Split files: $((after - before))"
```

If the other files in the directory can't have the same format as the split files (and presumably they can't or `split` would fail or overwrite them) then you could use an appropriate glob to get just the files that match the pattern. Soemthing like `splitfiles=(d??)`.

That failing you could see whether the `--verbose` option to `split` allows you to use `split_count=$(split --verbose a 2 d | wc -l)` or similar.

Comment: thank you i used the verbose option it's work fine !

Answer (score 0):

To be different, I will be counting the lines with `grep` utilizing the `--verbose` option:

```
split --verbose other_options file|grep -c ""
```

Example:

```
$ split --verbose -b 2 file|grep -c ""
60
# yeah, my file is pretty small, splitting on 2 bytes to produce numerous files
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split command with options -l and -a to specify prefix and suffix for the generated files.

Comment: This doesn't, on its own, help with getting the count of split files.